# SQL Server 2000 / SQL Server Management Studio 2008 - How to copy a database?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2000 server with SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and need to make a copy of a database.

Right-Click the database and pick Copy Database brings up the nice wizard. When I pick the destination server (the *same* server as the source server) the wizard happily tells me I need SQL Server 2005 or better and stops.

How can I make a copy of the database? I have no access to the computer other than through the management studio. Upgrading the server is not an option that is available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to backup the DB, then restore it with a the new name (and then get someone with access to do the clean up). This should be OK as long as you make sure that the physical file locations are updated when you choose a new db name.